# Customising Navigation View in Android support library

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-design-library

I am trying to implement navigation view using support library. Using primary color, the selected menu in navigation drawer is highlighted. But I want to remove the highlighted background of the selected item.

[image]

Comment: Post the code please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/yourColor</item>` 
 to your Theme (in ***style.xml***) and it will change the grey color.

setting the Color to `@android:color/transparent` will solve your problem.

If you want to change the BackgroundColor when item is selected or pressed create a ***selector*** as a drawable and add 
`<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/row_selector</item>`
 to the Theme

the selector (***row_selector***) could look somthing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_gray"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_gray"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I already tried colorControlHighlight. It worked. I hope it does not affect any other styles?